# get the position of picturebox that has been clicked

Tags: c#, windows, click, position, point

I want to get the position of the picturebox that has been cliked by the mouse,but i don't know how??
I mean the position of picturebox not the form that the picturebox on it.
thanks.

Comment: The position relative to what? Screen, form, parent control, ...?

Comment: @madd0: the position relative to picturebox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MUGAN's close. The Point you'll get from MouseEventArgs is the "screen" point of the mouse, where 0,0 is the top left of the entire monitor or desktop (however you want to think of it). To convert that to a "client" point within the PictureBox control, where 0,0 is the top left of that PictureBox, you'll need to use the Control.PointToClient() method:

```
private void pb_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    Point mouseDownLocation = (Control)sender.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    //here goes your if condition ...
}
```

Comment: i want if i change the location of the picturebox the position of specefic poin on the picturebox become fix,i want to get this fix point relative the picturebox.

Comment: I think I understand, and this does what you want. If you have a picture of a target in a PictureBox, and you click on the bulls-eye, PointToClient will return the same point coordinates regardless of where the PictureBox is on the form or where the form is on the screen.

Comment: ok,it's true,but in different Resolution the target position will be different,is it true?

Comment: That depends on what else is going on. An image that is 100 pixels by 100 pixels will still be 100x100 no matter what resolution you view it in; it'll just look smaller at 1280x1024 then at 800x600. If you are scaling your image, for instance if you maximize the window, then the picture is no longer 100x100, and areas of the picture will be at different coordinates.

Comment: However, if you keep track of the image's original size and its current size, you can still figure out what a coordinate on the stretched picture would be on the original picture by simple division: `originalX = currentX * (originalX / currentX)`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the event on the form instead of my picturebox. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
private void pb_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    Point mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    //here goes your if condition ...
}
```

Comment: Close, but MouseEventArgs' X and Y properties are the location of the mouse relative to the top left of the desktop, not the PictureBox.

Comment: i want the position relative picturebox,but this code is for if i click my form not picturebox.