# C# detect where user clicked on a image/Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

Is it possible to detected where user **clicked on a loaded image** or a bitmap on a C# form ? . just need it to be independent to image not screen locations !

Comment: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, WP7, ...?

Comment: @Sudantha you need both or one of them as the solutions would quite differ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the position of picturebox that has been clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235967/get-the-position-of-picturebox-that-has-been-clicked)

Comment: @Sudantha - good question, but this has been asked and answered many times on stackoverflow already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't tell us how you are displaying the image, so I am forced to guess.  I am assuming a picturebox displaying the image at it's native resolution.  So, in that case:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        picturebox1.MouseDown += picturebox1_MouseDown;       
    }

    private void picturebox1_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        if( (e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left )
        {
            var imagePos = e.Location; // that's it
        }
    }
}
```

If your image is scaled you will need to do the math.  Get the `Width` and `Height` of the control and figure out the ratio between them and the dimensions of your image.  Multiply the click position by that ratio.